# Understanding regular expressions in python delimiters, sub,

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to understand pattern matching and am very confsued by the code below. From what I can tell it checks to see if there is a chunk of 2-5 capital letters at the end of sent. Then it substitutes chunks delimited by numbers with '' and chuncks of capital lowercase capital lowercase by ''

I really don't think I'm understanding something... How do I decipher the re.sub lines?

I think the re.split is splitting sent based on the delimiter  where the . means a wildcard?

Could someone show me an illustrative example?

```
import re
    x=0
    y=[]
    while x<100:
        sent = raw_input("gimmie a sentence")
        if re.search('[A-Z]{2,5}$', sent):
            print("HERE")
            sent = re.sub('[0-9]+\.[0-9]+','<PAT1>', sent)
            print(sent)
            sent = re.sub(' [A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+ [^A-Z]', '<PAT2>', sent)
            print(sent)
            y+=re.split('<PAT.>', sent)
        x+= 1
        print(x)
        print(y)
    print y
```

Comment: Do you just not fully understand regular expressions or have you not read the documentation for `re.sub`? You seem to understand pieces of it fine, so I'm not sure where the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation of the `re` in above question-

### [A-Z]{2,5}$

```
[A-Z]{2,5}$
```

Options: Case insensitive; Exact spacing; Dot doesn't match line breaks; ^$ don't match at line breaks; Regex syntax only

- Match a single character in the range between “A” and “Z” (case insensitive) `[A-Z]{2,5}`

  - Between 2 and 5 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `{2,5}`
- Assert position at the end of the string, or before the line break at the end of the string, if any (line feed) `$`

### [0-9]+.[0-9]+

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
```

Options: Case insensitive; Exact spacing; Dot doesn't match line breaks; ^$ don't match at line breaks; Regex syntax only

- Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” `[0-9]+`

  - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`
- Match the character “.” literally `\.`
- Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” `[0-9]+`

  - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`

### [A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+ [^A-Z]

```
[A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+ [^A-Z]
```

Options: Case insensitive; Exact spacing; Dot doesn't match line breaks; ^$ don't match at line breaks; Regex syntax only

- Match a single character in the range between “A” and “Z” (case insensitive) `[A-Z]`
- Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z” (case insensitive) `[a-z]+`

  - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`
- Match the character “ ” literally
- Match a single character in the range between “A” and “Z” (case insensitive) `[A-Z]`
- Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z” (case insensitive) `[a-z]+`

  - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`
- Match the character “ ” literally
- Match any single character NOT in the range between “A” and “Z” (case insensitive) `[^A-Z]`

---

**re.sub('[0-9]+.[0-9]+','', sent)**

As documentation says, general format of `re.sub` is as below

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

Example-

```
>>> re.sub(r'def\s+([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)\s*\(\s*\):',r'static PyObject*\npy_\1(void)\n{','def myfunc():')
```

It will return

```
'static PyObject*\npy_myfunc(void)\n{'
```

Where `\1` captures the `group 1` i.e. `([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)`

Comment: Good copy/paste job !!!  I'm sure the OP now understands it perfectly. It helped a lot.

Comment: This looks copied straight from regex101 :)

Comment: So what is the point of the 5 in {2,5}? Wouldn't that give the same result as {2,3} since both would still match on 2 uppercase characters?

Comment: see Op's excerpt-`it checks to see if there is a chunk of 2-5 capital letters at the end of sent` then is **{2,3}={2,5}??** I tried to explain the the regex through some authentic description only since the OP demanded it